# CAN bus HW testing (STM32MP157CAA)

Tags: can

I am trying to write a c/c++ application which will exercise the Tx and Rx pins of the can interfaces (can0 and can1) available in the STM32MP157CAA.

Approach One I wrote an application which opens a socket on can0 and then writes into the Tx of can0 receive the same bytes on the Rx of can0. And same for the can1. I followed the loopback mechanism described in the below ST wiki: https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/How_to_send_or_receive_CAN_data#Hardware_self-test

This works. But, it turns out that the above loopback happens internally and doesn't actually send the packet through the Tx pin.

Approach Two Now, I am thinking if I can physically connect the Tx of can0 with the Rx of can1 using a female to female connector, and then open two separate sockets for can0 and can1, write on the Tx of can0 and then try receiving on the Rx of can1 - should that work? I have given it a quick try but doesn't seem to be working.

I am not sure technically if this approach is even valid. Can anyone please help to understand if this is at all possible? I wanted to double check before going into further investigation.

Approach Three If this doesn't work, then only other option would be to get another board and then physically connect the Tx of can0 of board A to the Rx of can0 of board B. But is that absolutely necessary? Shouldn't we be able to send from one can interface (can0) and receive on the other (can1) on the same board?

Note: My reference to can0 and can1 is from using SocketCAN. On the board schematics the two can interfaces are called can1 and can2 respectively. Just wanted to clarify.

I have attached the screenshot of the can1 and can2 pins below:

[image]

Do I need to use a CAN transceiver in Approach Three between the two CAN nodes to be able to talk to each other?

So far I have tested all of the above three approaches, and none are working.

Comment: There is nothing called "C/C++". Start with picking a single programming language. C is generally recommended for embedded systems. C++ is recommended if you need to make your life complicated :)

Answer (score 2):

> physically connect the Tx of can0 with the Rx of can1 [...] and then open two separate sockets for can0 and can1, write on the Tx of can0 and then try receiving on the Rx of can1 - should that work?

No, unfortunately not. CAN isn't a UART, and you can't think of it like that.

CAN is based on "*recessive*" and "*dominant*" bus states - asserting Tx will cause the discrete transceiver IC to put a "*dominant*" state on the bus. Any time the bus is in a "*dominant*" state, this will also be returned to the controller via the Rx signal (i.e: it can "*hear*" itself). All other nodes on the bus will also see this "*dominant*" state via their Rx signals.

When transmitting a frame onto a CAN bus, the arbitration and error checking is a core part of its operation that can't be skipped (or at least ***shouldn't*** be skipped if you're behaving properly).

When a node tries to transmit a frame, it will begin with a "*start of frame*", followed by the arbitration field (containing the frame's ID). If the Rx pin is ever in a state that is unexpected during this arbitration field, then the node will back off and abort the transmission.

I'd suggest as wired, your nodes don't even get past the "*start of frame*" without raising an transmit error.

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Data_frame) has a very good graphic showing the components in a frame.

> If this doesn't work, then only other option would be to get another board and then physically connect the Tx of can0 of board A to the Rx of can0 of board B. But is that absolutely necessary? Shouldn't we be able to send from one can interface (can0) and receive on the other (can1) on the same board?

It's not necessary, and as above, it's not a valid way of connecting CAN nodes. You *need* that transceiver in the middle, and the nodes *need* to be connected using the `CAN H` and `CAN L` signals, not `Tx` and `Rx`.

> Do I need to use a CAN transceiver in Approach Three between the two CAN nodes to be able to talk to each other?

Yes! :)

> I wrote an application which opens a socket on can0 and then writes into the Tx of can0 receive the same bytes on the Rx of can0

Be aware that CAN is also not an "*arbitary stream of bytes*" like UART. The data sent needs to be well-formed frames - with an ID, a payload and possibly some other flags.

Comment: That is quite enlightening for me, didn't have much experience about the CAN bus before - your explanation has put lot of light on it, really helpful.

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help, I hope things go well with the transcievers in place.

Answer (score 1):

I quickly looked and the controller you are using has two CAN ports. As the answer by @Attie rightly pointed out that you cannot treat CAN as UART. It follows a specific protocol and needs to be adhered to.

For you to test loopback you can simply hook the two CAN ports available to you. Transmit on one and receive on another.

You can refer to this template which uses HAL APIs for working with CAN -> [STM32 CAN HAL Example](https://github.com/timsonater/stm32-CAN-bus-example-HAL-API/blob/master/main.c)

Comment: I won't be able to use the HAL solution as the CAN peripheral in my case is connected to the A7 and not to the M4. The M4 apparently has a external loopback mode which (if configured properly) sends data out of the Tx port but not in internal mode. I am not sure if the expernal loopback mode is available in Linux driver as well, in the look out for it now.

Comment: My bad. Missed that. But in any case, I don't know why transmitting and receiving on the two different ports will have a problem as long as you are transmitting a valid CAN frame.

Comment: I think I need the tranceiver as explained by @Attie and Lundin in between the connection to make it working. I will try that and update asap. Thanks a lot to you all.

Answer (score 0):

@Attie has posted a good answer, but just to clarify some details:

- Loopback mode is used in the early development phase when the programmer wants to test things before even the evaluation board with real hardware arrives. That's all it is good for. It doesn't send anything out on the physical pins indeed.
- Connecting Tx and Rx of the same MCU will not make anyone happier, because when you send a live CAN frame, the CAN controller knows what it is sending and after it has sent most of the message all the way to the ACK field, it eagerly awaits response to see if anyone else is out there. If not, the frame is considered wrong and the error counter starts counting up. Therefore it is impossible to "speak with yourself" in CAN, you need at least 2 nodes.
- What you should do is indeed to hook up a second CAN controller to the bus and with CAN transceivers in between. If there are no transceivers then bus arbitration will not work, because what drives the lines to the dominant state is the CAN tranceiver.

Normally the 2nd node that you use is a CAN-to-USB listener adapter which you hook to a PC. Decent ones can be told to either be silent listeners or active ones that ACK frames. You need a CAN listener anyway, or otherwise it is impossible to do any form of CAN development.

Comment: Ordered a transceivers - will try using the transceivers and update here. Really great support from you all.